# Download data from hyperlinks into creating new folders using vba

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, download

[Image of data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws4bp.png)I am downloading some data from net using hyperlinks and to put downloaded data into folders created with names listed in A column.

Right now data is successfully downloaded when there is only one hyperlink for one folder, but now I also wants to put more than 2 files data into same folder.

Can anyone suggest a way to enhance the code to allow that?

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim ret As Long

'> This is where the files will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Users\a3rgcw\Downloads\"

Sub Download()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".zip"
        ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("D" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("F" & i).Value = "PR data successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("F" & i).Value = "Unable to download PR data"
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: show example of your actual data and desired behaviour

Comment: Plz find the image link in the text.

Comment: and what would you want to happen?

Comment: Above code creates new folders in Downloads folder using names in 'A' column and from hyperlink it downloads zip file in respective folder. But when there are 2 or more links for the same folder it does downlaod only one zip file. I want all corresponding zip files in same named folder in 'A' column, preferably with same name when it was uploded to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP clarifications he doesn't have hyperlinks

as per your shown code and link, your code doesn't actually create new folders, rather it creates many new files in "C:\Users\a3rgcw\Downloads\" folder (i.e. your `FolderName` variable

and since those files names are built with `ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".zip"`, then for every same value in any column A cell it overwrites the existing file with the new one

furthermore your link shows column "C" with hyperlinks while your code read them from column "D" (`ws.Range("D" & i).Value`

to avoid files overwriting you could define zip name out of a combination of "folder" name (from column A cells) and file name (from corresponding hyperlink address) like follows (assuming your code assumption for hyperlinks column is the valid one)

```
Sub Download()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        strPath = FolderName & _
                  ws.Range("A" & i).Value & "-" & _
                  GetName(ws.Range("D" & i)) & ".zip"
        ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("D" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("F" & i).Value = "PR data successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("F" & i).Value = "Unable to download PR data"
        End If    
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetName(rng As Range) As String
    With rng
        GetName = Right(.Value, Len(.Value) - InStrRev(.Value, "/"))
    End With
End Function
```

which could also be refactored as follows:

```
Sub Download()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            strPath = FolderName & _
                      cell.Value & "-" & _
                      GetName(cell.Offset(, 3)) & ".zip"
            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, cell.Offset(, 3).Value, strPath, 0, 0)
            cell.Offset(, 5).Value = IIf(ret = 0, "PR data successfully downloaded", "Unable to download PR data")
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetName(rng As Range) As String
    With rng
        GetName = Right(.Value, Len(.Value) - InStrRev(.Value, "/"))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. But I am getting Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range error at line:     "With rng.Hyperlinks(1)" also for your information providing sample hyperlink: https://tiweb-in.industrysoftware.automation.com/prdata/cgi-bin/n_prdata_download_file.cgi?pr_id=7591216&amp;export_control=itsitename=tiweb-in.industrysoftware.automation.com/prdata/cgi-bin&amp;filename=8hhG_bciE0wCEJTIFLHrHyRcGY60AVsJ0wLDRIs2N_rYd_5bvcWdbUxQM7b54Oj45z2WsG7xxrw
And associated file name with this link is: 7591216_01_1.7z

Comment: Did you check which column do you have hyperkynks in? Is it column C (as per linked image) or D (as per your code)?

Comment: Still error persists irrespective of hyperlinks in C or D column.

Comment: step through your code and use Immediate Window to check variables values. for instance once you enter `GetName()` function, type `?rng.Address, rng.Value, rng.Hyperlinks.Count` in the Immediate Window and press return to see returned values

Comment: I don't know if I did it right way or not. I went to Immediate window -> typed GetName() in main pane/window -> entered ?rng.Address, rng.Value, rng.Hyperlinks.Count in immediate window. Getting compile error: Expected: =

Comment: Also .xlsm file is available here you can refer if you want: http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/vba-to-unzip-folders-from-dir.32984/#post-195625

Comment: to step though your code you have to 1) put your mouse cursor inside any `Download()` code line 2) press F8 to have macro start 3) press F8 to jump to next statement to be executed which is yellow highlighted 4) at any time you can query relevant variable values through Immediate Window . For instance, once the highlighted line is `Function GetName(rng As Range) As String` you can type `?rng.Address, rng.Value, rng.Hyperlinks.Count`

Comment: I am getting ?rng.Address-> $D$1, rng.Value -> correct hyperlink address and rng.Hyperlinks.Count -> 0. These links are not hyperlinked. There is only address in cell craeted by formula.

Comment: Great, both codes are working fine. But 1) I would like to append string from column B instead of from hyperlink address as links has more than 64 char. after "/". 2) Also would like to know difference between 2 codes. 3_ One last thing want to make <Const FolderName As String = "C:\Users\a3rgcw\Downloads\"> as variable as per different machines. or take the path mentioned in cell.

Comment: first off, If I solved your _original_ question then please mark answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: 1) replace `GetName (cell.Offset(, 3)) & ".zip"` with `cell.Offset(, 1) & ".zip"` 2) it uses `With - End With` block to reference an object ("Sheet1" `Worksheet` object in this case) and access its members (properties or methods) by simply typing a dot (`.`) and it iterates a range (`.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))`) through a `For Each cell in Range` construct which is much faster than a ` For i = 1 To LastRow` one + accessing range cells through such syntax as `.Range("A" & i)`ing = ...`, add `Dim FolderName As String` after `Dim cell As Range`

Comment: 3) remove or comment out `Const FolderName As String = "C:\Users\a3rgcw\Downloads\"`, add `Dim FolderName As String` (for instance after `Dim cell As Range`) and add `FolderName = .Range("E1")` right after `With Sheets("Sheet1")` (change "E1" to whatever "Sheet1" cell address you are writing _path_ into)

Comment: Thank you so much again, for your help. I would also like to unzip them after downloading files. Here is some code with me:     Next i
   
    UnZipMe

End Sub

Sub UnZipMe()

Dim str_FILENAME As String, str_DESTINATION As String
Dim c As Range

    'Loop through all zip files in the directory
   str_FILENAME = Dir(FolderName & ".zip")
 
    Do While Len(str_FILENAME) > 0
        Call Unzip1(FolderName & str_FILENAME)
        str_FILENAME = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Comment: you are welcome. that of the unzipping is a completely _new_ issue: you'd better post it in a new question along with your code attempts and all relevant information